# DataTables-Find data in a table, but do not filter on the server side

Tags: datatables, server-side

I want to load the data on the server side (server side) but when looking for any content I do not want to be server side with sql queries for example:

```php
if( !empty($params['search']['value']) ) {   
        $where .=" WHERE ( nombre LIKE '%".$params['search']['value']."%' )";    
        $where .=" OR employee_salary LIKE '".$params['search']['value']."%' ";
        $where .=" OR employee_age LIKE '".$params['search']['value']."%' )";
    }
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: So, do you really *need* serverside processing? If it is about the filter, you can overrule the search capabilities and perform a "fake search" within visible rows.

Comment: Sounds like an odd requirement, but you could load the data as part of the page load, build a 'normal' html table then apply the datatables plugin to it.  That way all the seaching, paging etc would be client-side only.

Comment: I can email the code and help me solve it? I just want you to be able to search for any column